# Rails: Less can import sass file, but vice versa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, sass, less

I just noticed that while a `.less` file can `@import` a `.scss` file, vice verso doesn't work. Is this a limitation to Sass? I have both `less-rails` and `sass-rails` in my Ruby On Rails project.

Comment: I checked but I was unable to import `.scss` file in a `.less` file. It just imports `.scss` as `css`. I couldn't use variables which was set in `variables.scss` in my `.less` file. It seemed to me that LESS compiler cannot parse sass syntax.

Comment: Do you have less-rails and sass-rails in your Gemfile?